# Cura UI slice progress bar read data from CuraEngine

Tags: ultimaker-cura

I have a simple browser based interface that uses php's exec function to run CuraEngine on an stl file that a client uploads. It is based on the source code provided by Jesse Campbell in his 3dpartprice.com site.  I am looking for a way to make a progress bar of the slicing process. Does CuraEngine output data about the slice progress? The Cura app with a GUI has a progress bar that updates while the model is being sliced. What data is driving this progress bar? Any suggestions of different approaches to get a progress bar from CuraEngine's slicing process?

Answer (score 2):

CuraEngine transfer the progress and slice data with the help of the C++ library [libArcus](https://github.com/Ultimaker/libArcus) which is a wrapper around the Google Protobuf library.
The Python binding for libArcus are [pyArcus](https://github.com/Ultimaker/pyArcus).

If you want to send messages to CuraEngine with Arcus check how it is done in the [CuraEngineBackend](https://github.com/Ultimaker/Cura/tree/main/plugins/CuraEngineBackend) plugin on the Cura side and the [communication](https://github.com/Ultimaker/CuraEngine/tree/main/src%2Fcommunication) source code for the CuraEngine side.

But please take note of the CuraEngine, libArcus, and pyArcus licenses these also apply when using them in a cloud slicer.